# How does one change/update the time interval in an NSTimer?

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

I need to change the time interval once it has fired once

```
secondTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(count, target:self, selector: Selector("update1"), userInfo:nil, repeats:false)
```

for example I want to change count to 1

Comment: Note - an extremely common pattern is, *never use* a repeating timer; simply call to create a new one each loop, and then you can use any time you wish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Invalidate the timer, and create a new one with a different time interval.

You can change the fire time. So if you want to change the time interval after the first firing only, create the timer with that time interval, then change the firing time so that the timer is fired the first time at the time you want.